# GetPixel(ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight) throws exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I have a 1080P monitor. Doing

```
int j Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
int k = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
_Bitmap.GetPixel(j, k).GetBrightness();
```

(_Bitmap size is equal to my screen bounds), it throws an exception saying "Parameter must be positive and < height".

Comment: Is the `Bitmap` the same size as your screen?  What are you trying to do here?

Comment: @BJ Myers Sorry for not being clear enough. The bitmap is a screenshot of my screen. So yes, it is the size of my screen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Width and Height start counting at 1, the indexes used in GetPixel() start at 0. So when trying to acces the Pixel at (Width,Height) nothing is found

To correct the error change the code to (for example):

```
int width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
int height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;

_Bitmap.GetPixel(width-1,height-1).GetBrightness();
```